# PhpUnit and Symfony: Mock Service not working

Tags: symfony, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and PHPUnit 5.7 and I'm trying to mock a service for testing an api controller.

The controller:

```
class ApiTestManager extends BaseApiController{
    public function getAction(): View
    {
        $response = $this->get('app.business.test_api')->getResponse();
        return $this->view($response);
    }}
```

The test class:

```
class ApiTestManagerTest extends WebTestCase {
public function testApiCall()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $service = $this->getMockBuilder(ApiTestManager::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['getResponse'])
        ->getMock()
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getResponse')
        ->will($this->returnValue(new Response()));

    $client->getContainer()->set('app.business.test_api', $service);
    $client->request('GET', 'de/api/v1/getResponse');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}}
```

I've spent hours in trying to find the mistake, but everytime I execute this test it gives me following error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker::getResponse()
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? Thanks :)

Comment: I'd suggest use the fully qualified class name as parameter for `getMockBuilder()`. And, did you extend the correct WebTestCase class, the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase`?

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference...yes its the correct WebTestCase :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe? it's the only thing i see...

```
$service = $this->getMockBuilder(ApiTestManager::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['getResponse'])
        ->getMock();
$service->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getResponse')
        ->will($this->returnValue(new Response()));
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you...but I don't understand why :D Do you know why I can't chain the methods like I did before?

Comment: really don't understand why, as you can see`getMock()` returning the result of `generator`, but i've always seen this way on documentation, examples and projects...